# Am i using correctly Unit of Work here? (Entityi Framework 4 POCO)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, unit-of-work

I found some examples of how to create unit of work with ef4, i haven't used di/ioc and i would like to keep things simple and this an example (90% inspired) and i think it's ok but since i am looking at a pattern to use from now on i would like to ask an opinion one last time.

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
 {
     void Save();
 }

public partial class TemplateEntities : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    ....
    public void Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUser(string username);
    string GetUserNameByEmail(string email);
    void AddUser(User userToAdd);
    void UpdateUser(User userToUpdate);
    void DeleteUser(User userToDelete);
    //some other
}
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository, IDisposable
{
    public TemplateEntities ctx;
    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unit)
    {
        ctx = unit as TemplateEntities;
    }
    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        return (from u in ctx.Users
                where u.UserName == username
                select u).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    public string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        return (from u in ctx.Users
                where u.Email == email
                select u.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    public void AddUser(User userToAdd)
    {
        ctx.Users.AddObject(userToAdd);
    }
    public void UpdateUser(User userToUpdate)
    {
        ctx.Users.Attach(userToUpdate);
        ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(userToUpdate, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    }
    public void DeleteUser(User userToDelete)
    {
        ctx.Users.Attach(userToDelete);
        ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(userToDelete, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ctx != null)
            ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And finally

```
    public class BogusMembership : MembershipProvider
    {
        public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, bool autoemail, string fullname)
        {
            IUnitOfWork ctx = new TemplateEntities();
            using (UserRepository rep = new UserRepository(ctx))
            {
                using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    if (rep.GetUser(username) != null)
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
                    if (requiresUniqueEmail && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rep.GetUserNameByEmail(email)))
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
                    User userToCreate = new User
                    {
                        UserName = username,
                        PassWord = EncodePassword(password),
                        FullName = fullname,
                        Email = email,
                        AutoEmail = autoemail
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        rep.AddUser(userToCreate);
                        ctx.Save();
                        tran.Complete();
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After getting rid if the IUnitOfWork and IDisposal the CreateUser looks like this:

```
        public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, bool autoemail, string fullname)
        {
            using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (TemplateEntities ctx = new TemplateEntities())
                {
                    UserRepository rep = new UserRepository(ctx);
                    //OtherRepository rep2 = new OtherRepository(ctx);
                    if (rep.GetUser(username) != null)
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
                    if (requiresUniqueEmail && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rep.GetUserNameByEmail(email)))
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
                    User userToCreate = new User
                    {
                        UserName = username,
                        PassWord = EncodePassword(password),
                        FullName = fullname,
                        Email = email,
                        AutoEmail = autoemail
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        rep.AddUser(userToCreate);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        tran.Complete();
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks basically OK. A few suggestions though:

- You should not let the repository dispose the `TemplateEntities`. The reason for this is that when you need two repositories within one transaction, you have a problem. You should move the responsibility of disposing the `TemplateEntities` to the same level as the `TransactionScope`;
- The `TransactionScope` should be moved to a higher level. Preferably, the  `TemplateEntities` should be instantiated within a `TransactionScope`;
- You don't have to create the `Save` wrapper if it does not contain functionality. If you specify the `void SaveChanges()` on the `IUnitOfWork` interface, this will pick up the `SaveChanges` of the `TemplateEntities`;
- Personally I would not have `string GetUserNameByEmail(...)` but rather `User GetUserByEmail(...)` because then this will also serve your purpose and you have the advantage of not having two methods that search by e-mail address when you later need the `User GetUserByEmail(...)`;
- You may want to think about making `ctx` private, or at least a private setter like `public TemplateEntities Ctx { get; private set; }`;
- You could create an abstract repository with methods like the example below. This will save you a lot of dull typing in the long run:

-

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    void Delete(TEntity entity);

    /* ... */
}

public abstract class AbstractRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    public TemplateEntities ctx;

    public AbstractRepository(IUnitOfWork unit)
    {
        ctx = unit as TemplateEntities;
    }

    protected abstract ObjectSet<TEntity> Entites { get; }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        Entities.Attach(entity);
        ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
    }

    /* ... */
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
    User GetUser(string username);

    /* ... */
}

public class UserRepository : AbstractRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unit)
        : base(unit)
    {
    }

    protected override ObjectSet<User> Entites
    {
        get { return ctx.Users; }
    }

    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        return (from u in ctx.Users
                where u.UserName == username
                select u).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: You think that i should get rid of interface IUnitOfWork?

Comment: I don't know, maybe. I don't see the added value with this setup. Normally, you would add an extra layer of abstraction when you e.g. have two databases which are both managed by the unit of work. Then the repository would get his context from the unit of work. Basically, `TemplateEntities` already is a unit of work anyway.

Comment: I will paste in my post the new CreateUser method so you can tell me if it is any way better. I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Yep, look better. Don't forget the other suggestions though :).

Comment: The base class, i won't :)  i mean i won't forget :)